# Working With An Unknown Number of Views (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to conceptualize an idea for a very rudimentary app that acts similar to a File Browser.  I am using a web service to provide me a listing of files/folders in a directory (which is working well using a NSURL session to gather the data, and a third-party library to parse the data; it's XML).

At the current moment, here is my layout in the Storyboard;
[image: Navigation Controller -> TableViewController -> NextTableViewController]

While this is functional, it only works up to two levels.  The user can launch the app, tap a folder, which passes the index path to the "NextTableViewController," calls a function to gather the data of *that* folder, and presents it.

My question is; what would I do next?  There obviously could be an unknown number of TableViewControllers necessary, since there could be many subfolders as the user taps through.  I seek to keep the Navigation Controller structure, so the user can go back "one step" at a time.  Conceptually, could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unlimited levels, you really only need 1 table view controller.  Just wire the segue from the prototype cell to the viewController icon at the top and select *Show* from the pop-up.  When you run, this will push a new instance of the table view controller each time you select a cell.  Use `prepareForSegue` to configure the next table view controller.

[image: Wiring a table view controller to itself]

Comment: Thanks, @vacawama!  This worked very well, and I had no idea this was even possible!  I have some follow-up questions on functionality after using this structure, but I will address them in a different post.  Thank you again!